# VS 2008 Resources - Can't see Company Name in file details althouth CompanyName added in .rc

Tags: windows, visual-c++

Looked for the relevant answer but found nothing.

I've added **COMPANY_NAME**
in my .rc file but still can't see Company Name in the exe file
(right click->properties->details)

Here is a part of my .rc file :

```
VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
 FILEVERSION CURRENT_VERSION
 PRODUCTVERSION CURRENT_VERSION
 FILEFLAGSMASK 0x17L
#ifdef _DEBUG
 FILEFLAGS 0x1L
#else
 FILEFLAGS 0x0L
#endif
 FILEOS 0x4L
 FILETYPE 0x1L
 FILESUBTYPE 0x0L
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "040d04b0"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "FileDescription", DESCRIPTION
            VALUE "CompanyName", COMPANY_NAME
            VALUE "FileVersion", CURRENT_VERSION_STR
            VALUE "InternalName", NAME
            VALUE "LegalCopyright", COPYRIGHT
            VALUE "OriginalFilename", EXE_NAME
            VALUE "ProductName", PRODUCT_NAME
            VALUE "ProductVersion", CURRENT_VERSION_STR
        END
    END
    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        VALUE "Translation", 0x40d, 1200
    END
```

I have to change something else?

What should I do, so my file will include Company Name filed?

Comment: You **do** see all of the other fields, right?  If so, there are a couple unlikely possibilities: (1) `DESCRIPTION` might end with a line continuation character, making the `CompanyName` part of the description; (2) `COMPANY_NAME` might be empty, which you can check by temporarily hard-coding a string, like `"company name test"` for the `CompanyName` value instead of the symbol you have.  Otherwise, are you **positive** the new resource was compiled and linked to your executable?

Comment: I've also noticed that Windows seems to cache this information, so you might try renaming the file.  You could also resort to a resource editor to make sure the information is actually in the file.

Comment: I've tried to look for line continuation character,      
COMPANY_NAME declared properly and      
I rebuilt the project.
                                   
I've opened the file in resHacker and I can see there the "CompanyName" but in my files details this filed still missing. 
screenshot:                 
http://postimage.org/image/a1j1gida3/
                
     
What else can i do?
          
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The Explorer does not show CompanyName in file details at all!

You may append the company name to LegalCopyright of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Company column to the columns in Windows Explorer and through this check the value for the created dll.

In case it's not clear how to do this: Switch to Detail view, then right-click on a column header and select "More" at the bottom.